# Do I need to specify calling convention in both header and source files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Do I need to specify calling convention in both header and source files?

For example,

**header.h**

```
void __cdecl Foo();
```

**source.cpp**

```
void __cdecl Foo()
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2017):

> For non-static class functions, if the function is defined out-of-line, **the calling convention modifier does not have to be specified on the out-of-line definition**. That is, for class non-static member methods, the calling convention specified during declaration is assumed at the point of definition. Given this class definition:
>
> ```
> struct CMyClass {
>    void __cdecl mymethod();
> };
> ```
>
> this
>
> ```
> void CMyClass::mymethod() { return; }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to this:
>
> ```
> void __cdecl CMyClass::mymethod() { return; }
> ```

Comment: Doesn't this only apply to member functions? Also, how can the callee ever ignore calling convention (as implied by your last paragraph)?

Comment: The calling convention matters equally on **both** caller and callee sides. It has to match.

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah, removed that last thing. I do not know why the docs are all specific to non-static member functions (for all the calling conventions).